# On the convergence of a sequence of random variables indexed by random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X_k$ be a decreasing and uniformly bounded sequence of  nonnegative random variables which is completely determined by $\mathcal F_k$ (not necessarily $\sigma(X_1,...,X_k)$). Mathematically $ X_{k+1}\leq X_k$ a.s. and $0\leq X_k\leq M$ a.s.  for some $M\in\mathbb R$. Let $\tau_n$ be a sequence of $\mathcal F_k$-stopping time such that $\tau_n\to \infty $ almost surely. Assume one has:
\begin{align}
X_{\tau_n} \stackrel{\text{ a.s. }}{\longrightarrow} 0  \text{ as  } n\to\infty \ \ \ 
\end{align}
I think that this does not imply $X_k\to 0$ a.s., or in probability. But if it would hold for all sequences of stopping time, then we would have the implication $X_k\to 0$. Also if we would have $\tau_n\leq K_n\in\mathbb R$ a.s. then we would have $X_k\to 0$. That is all I know...

**Question.** Can we actually say something about the convergence of $X_k$? Some type of convergence, maybe under additional conditions?

I'm also satisfied by citing some references on this. Thank you!

Comment: "I think that this does not imply $X_k \to 0$." What is the counterexample?

Comment: I should have been more clear. I wanted to say that with the assumption $X_{\tau_n} \to 0$ only, we cannot say $X_k\to 0$ in general. So, not with the additional assumptions on $X_k$.

Comment: Yes I understood that; so what is the counterexample?

Comment: @Shalop Maybe I can give you a name where these kind of random variables are discussed "Limit Theorems for Randomly Indexed Sequences of Random Variables" by Krzysztof Kubacki. I'm new in these kind of things, namely randomly indexed random variables, btw.

Comment: It was just a rhetorical question. No counterexample can exist, by the answer below.

Comment: Yes, of course with the **additional assumptions** on $X_k$ (decreasing etc)...Thank you again with your answer!

Comment: No problem! And yes, you can definitely find many counterexamples if $X_k$ is not nonincreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following elementary statement: if $x_n$ is a sequence of nonnegative real numbers which is decreasing and has a subsequence converging to $0$, then the entire sequence $x_n$ converges to $0$.

You have $X_{T_n} \to 0$ a.s. for some (fixed) sequence of stopping times $T_n$.

This implies that (almost surely) the random sequence $(X_n)$ has a subsequence which converges to $0$.

But the random sequence $(X_n)$ is almost surely nondecreasing. This implies that $X_n \to 0$ a.s. You don't even need $T_n$ to be stopping times, just that they tend to $\infty$ a.s.

Comment: Oeps.... Sometimes the simplest get forgotten. I was so long getting deep in the theory of randomly indexed random variables and all strong conditions to get nice kind of convergence, so that I totally forgot using the simple facts that I am dealing with. Thank you very much !!!